# In a family of six(how many in all including you)

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is a useful phrase. Let's say you want to say that you are the eldest amongst your sibling. Then we include your parents. You say:

> I am the eldest **in a family of six.**

When you say that, is your family's total number is **6** or **7**?

Comment: How can there be seven people in a family of six? The number that you've specified is the number.

Comment: It's just that I wasn't absolutely sure of that. I didn't use my common sense, and I considered the possibility of grammar rule exceptions, because you know, English is a weird, annoyingly complicated language and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are included as you are talking about your **part** in that **group**.

So the total number of that family would be six.